# registering 2 components which inherits same interface

Tags: c#, autofac, ioc-container

I am new in autofac and I am trying to understand the concept. So basically going through the sample on their website. I was playing around with some code and I didn't understand the following.

If I register two similar components like **todaywriter** and **yesterdaywriter** as below and resolve my container, It only writes out the last registered the one, so in this case, it will only write out today's date and ignore the yesterday's date. What is actually happening? I can't register 2 components inherits from same interface? If I can how will I display both of them.

```
class Program
{
    private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();

        builder.RegisterType<yesterdayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
        builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
        Container = builder.Build();

        WriteDate();
    }

    public static void WriteDate()
    {
        // Create the scope, resolve your IDateWriter,
        // use it, then dispose of the scope.
        using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var writer = scope.Resolve<IDateWriter>();
            writer.WriteDate();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}



// This implementation of the IOutput interface
// is actually how we write to the Console. Technically
// we could also implement IOutput to write to Debug
// or Trace... or anywhere else.
public class ConsoleOutput : IOutput
{
    public void Write(string content)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(content);
    }
}

// This interface helps decouple the concept of
// "writing output" from the Console class. We
// don't really "care" how the Write operation
// happens, just that we can write.
public interface IOutput
{
    void Write(string content);
}

// This interface decouples the notion of writing
// a date from the actual mechanism that performs
// the writing. Like with IOutput, the process
// is abstracted behind an interface.
public interface IDateWriter
{
    void WriteDate();
}

// This TodayWriter is where it all comes together.
// Notice it takes a constructor parameter of type
// IOutput - that lets the writer write to anywhere
// based on the implementation. Further, it implements
// WriteDate such that today's date is written out;
// you could have one that writes in a different format
// or a different date.
public class TodayWriter : IDateWriter
{
    private IOutput _output;
    public TodayWriter(IOutput output)
    {
        this._output = output;
    }

    public void WriteDate()
    {
        this._output.Write(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
    }
}

// This TodayWriter is where it all comes together.
// Notice it takes a constructor parameter of type
// IOutput - that lets the writer write to anywhere
// based on the implementation. Further, it implements
// WriteDate such that today's date is written out;
// you could have one that writes in a different format
// or a different date.
public class yesterdayWriter : IDateWriter
{
    private IOutput _output;
    public yesterdayWriter(IOutput output)
    {
        this._output = output;
    }

    public void WriteDate()
    {
        this._output.Write(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code sample, your container contains 2 registrations that match the `IDateWriter` service. When you resolve the `IDateWriter` service, `Autofac` will give you the latest registration, in your case `TodayWriter`.

If you want to resolve all your `IDateWriter` you can resolve `IEnumerable<IDateWriter>`.

```
foreach (var writer in scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IDateWriter>>())
{
    writer.WriteDate();
}
```

---

If you want to go further, you may want an aggregated `IDateWriter`.

For example :

```
public class AggregatedDateWriter : IDateWriter
{
    public AggregatedDateWriter(IEnumerable<IDateWriter> writers)
    {
        this._writers = writers; 
    }


    private readonly IEnumerable<IDateWriter> _writers;


    public void WriteDate()
    {
        foreach (IDateWriter writer in this._writers)
        {
            writer.WriteDate();
        }
    }
}
```

If you try to register this type you will have the following error message

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: Circular component dependency detected: ConsoleApplication75.AggregatedDateWriter

Which is normal because you try to resolve all `IDateWriter` when the `AggregatedDateWriter` is activated.

To avoid this you can change the way the components are registered.

```
builder.RegisterType<yesterdayWriter>()
        .Named<IDateWriter>("concrete");
builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>()
        .Named<IDateWriter>("concrete");
builder.RegisterType<AggregatedDateWriter>()
        .As<IDateWriter>()
        .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "writers", 
                        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IDateWriter>>("concrete"));
```

The `WithParameter` method tell `Autofac` how it should handle arguments of the component. If your `AggregatedDateWriter` constructor has a `value` parameter of type `String`. You can use the `.WithParameter("value", "anyString")` method to let `Autofac` use this value in the constructor. In this case, the first parameter will look for the parameter name `writers` and the second parameter will tell `Autofac` to use the result of  `c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IDateWriter>>("concrete")` for its value.

If you still want to go further, you can generate a proxy using `Castle.Core` that will automatically generated the `AggregatedDateWriter` for you and register this proxy using a custom `IRegistrationSource`.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. what is concrete standing for there?

Comment: @batmaci what do you mean by concrete standing ?

Comment: Sorry, I am being silly. You defined named service. I should look into usage of this better. thanks again :-)

Comment: If you just dont mind, could you explain the 3rd one what exactly it does? This one I mean. 

builder.RegisterType<AggregatedDateWriter>()
        .As<IDateWriter>()
        .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "writers", 
                        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IDateWriter>>("concrete"));